# jqGrid Dynamic Columns and Grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid for my grids. I am struggling with an issue. My client wants a grid that looks like this:

[image: Grid Sample]

The problem here is the dynamic columns and grouping of Auto Makes. I really am not sure how to accomplish this. The idea is the count on the far right is a sum of the auto make grouping. The auto makes can change depending on the results of the rest of the query.

I tried to just use the row grouping function in jqGrid and accomplished something similar but it visual was very different. He is insisting on this format.

If anyone can point me in the right direction to figure this out it would be great. I really am not sure where to start with this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything or gotten close? Anything for us to work off of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for header grouping
Try this,

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar